# Condtion in sql query using if

Tags: sql, sql-server

`SELECT T1.[AcctCode],T1.[AcctName] FROM OACT T1`

I need `T1.AcctName` as `operating cost` `if T1.AcctCode like 61`
 Please help me to get this thing.

Comment: Are you searching for `case` statement?

Comment: will be better. but issue should be solved, either with if or case . @AndyKorneyev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT T1.[AcctCode],
       AcctName = CASE WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = 61 
                       THEN 'operating cost' 
                       ELSE T1.[AcctName]
                  END
FROM OACT T1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.AcctName AS operating cost FROM OACT T1 WHERE T1.AcctCode=61
```